# Asterisk ( with FreePBX ) & Openfire Phone Mappings Configuration

Tags: asterisk, openfire, pbx, candy

I have some problem understanding the parameter matching between FreePBX configuration and Openfire's ( through the SIP plugin ):

Every server's component is on the same server ( vm.com ), I insert my settings ( 2nd screen ), then the server is still identified as unregistered ( 1st screen )

In the 4th screen there are FreePBX's configurations before I clicked "Apply Config"

If I click the button "test" in the 2nd screen, it remains in a infinite loop state.. And I can't get any confirm from it.

Any advice? 
Sorry for my english, thanks in advice.

[image: Openfire] 
[image: Openfire]

[image: Openfire]

[image: FreePBX]

Answer (score 0):

You have put your server name instead of vm.com in openfire settings.

Comment: i not know how on vm.com work your app, but looks like something wrong here.

Comment: vm.com is a virtual DNS for my virtual machine